# Swift timer returning previous if statement without criteria being met

Tags: swift, timer

I have a workout timer which goes like this. 30 seconds of working out -> 10 seconds of rest. I have an if statement to print out some text, but for some reason they are both rapidly called at the same time instead of just the one that fits the `If` criteria. Any idea why? I've tried adding `return` at the bottom of each case but then neither are called after the first fire.

```
var restBreaks: [Double] = [30, 60]
    
    var startTime = Date.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate
    Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.01, repeats: true) { [self] timer in
        
        let time = Date.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate - startTime
        
        self.seconds = time
        
        print(time)
        
        for restLocation in restBreaks {
            if time >= restLocation && time <= restLocation + 10 {
                print("RESTING")
            } else {
                print("WORKOUT")
            }
        }
        
        // Restarting timer
        if time >= 90 {
            startTime = Date.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate
        }
    }
```

**Result:** (when is resting period) as you can see it's printing out "WORKOUT!"

```
RESTING
WORKOUT!
RESTING
RESTING
RESTING
WORKOUT!
RESTING
RESTING
RESTING
WORKOUT!
RESTING
```

Comment: show the code for "restBreaks" and the data in it, so we can replicate the issue.
Did you mean to have: "for restLocation in self.restBreaks { ...}"?

Comment: @workingdog I have updated my code to show more of it. :)

Comment: @workingdog You will notice that workout is called even when it's resting. even with the return statement.

Comment: This is because of 60, say that time is 35 then the condition is true for 30 but false for 60

Comment: @JoakimDanielson okay, so it's this line that's giving me issues? `if time >= restLocation && time <= restLocation + 10 `?

Comment: Yes that is the one I meant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code logic is not what you are trying to achieve. Try something like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var seconds: Double = 0.0
    @State private var restDuration: Double = 4.0
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("workout timers").onAppear {
            var breakIndex = 0
            // must be of the form x, and at least x+restDuration
            let restBreaks: [Double] = [5.0, 15.0]
            
            var startTime = Date.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate
            Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true) { timer in
                let time = Date.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate - startTime
                self.seconds = time

                if breakIndex < restBreaks.count {
                    if time >= restBreaks[breakIndex] && time <= restBreaks[breakIndex] + restDuration {
                        print("---> RESTING time: \(time) breakIndex: \(breakIndex) rest at: \(restBreaks[breakIndex]) to: \(restBreaks[breakIndex] + restDuration)")
                    } else {
                        print("WORKOUT time: \(time)")
                    }
                }
                
                if breakIndex+1 < restBreaks.count && time >= restBreaks[breakIndex] + restDuration {
                    breakIndex = breakIndex + 1
                }
 
                // Restarting timer
                if time >= 20 {
                    startTime = Date.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate
                    breakIndex = 0
                }
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This code has some serious issues since it seems to create an infinite amount of timer objects. Add a `print(timer)` as the first line in the closure and you'll see it has a new memory address each time, hence a new timer object. @user Don't implement this code until it has been fixed.

Comment: I've put a print(timer) as the first line in the closure and I only get 1 timer, as it should. I do not get an infinite number of timers.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Could it be creating a new timer object due to the code being used .onAppear?

Comment: I tried it in a playground when I got this behavior, I can try it in a ordinary project as well.

Comment: Note the code in ".onAppear{...}" is just an example of a possible approach. 
Packaging the code into a useful function/class, starting/ending of the timer 
is up to the App.

Comment: The issue I saw only happened in a playground and not in a real app so there is no memory issue with the code. But I am a little confused about what the code is actually doing and for how long the workout time is and how long the rest time is but if OP is happy with it then i guess it is ok.

Comment: The code does this:
you start workout (say on the treadmill) at time zero. At time 5 sec, you take a break 
for 4 secs. After the break you start workout. At time 15 sec, you take another break for 4 secs.
And so on until the max time 20 sec is reached. Then you start the whole thing again for ever.
Because this is a timer at each second you can do something (here just print, but it could be measure your pulse) when you 
are in workout or resting.

Comment: So one full cycle is 20 seconds, 5+4+6+4+1. And then a new cycle starts with 5 so it’s basically 6 sec workout 4 sec rest. Interesting but a bit complicated.

Comment: yeah, this is just an example of some code to think about, in particular an alternative to looping over restBreaks at every seconds. Not knowing what the app is about I'm just guessing what @user wants.